# Java CharsetDecoder inserting space after every character

Tags: java, utf-8, groovy

I'm attempting to use this code (found on Stackoverflow) to remove invalid UTF-8 characters:

```
def text = file.text
CharsetDecoder utf8Decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
utf8Decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
utf8Decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(text.getBytes().length * 2)
CharBuffer cbuf = bytes.asCharBuffer()
cbuf.put(text)
cbuf.flip()
CharBuffer parsed = utf8Decoder.decode(bytes);
println parsed.toString()
```

The output I get looks like this:

```
 < d o c u m e n t >
     < t i t l e > S o me  T i t l e   < / t i t l e >
     < s i t e > A S i t e < / s i t e >
```

Any ideas on why it is behaving like this?

Comment: Is there any postable input you can provide?

Comment: Shouldn't you specify the encoding in `text.getBytes()`? I doubt that's the cause of the problem, though. Also, are you specifying any encoding when you open/read the file?

Comment: I suspect file.text is using the default platform character encoding, but it [doesn't seem to be specified](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#getText()). You should probably be using the one that lets you [specify the encoding](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#getText(java.lang.String)), or else [File.getBytes()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#getBytes()) to get the raw bytes. Otherwise, the bytes have already been converted once already, quite possibly with the wrong encoding.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why this didn't work, but this is what fixed it (code is in Groovy, not Java):

```
file.withInputStream { stream ->
    CharsetDecoder utf8Decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
    utf8Decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
    utf8Decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
    def reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, utf8Decoder))
    def line = null

    def sb = new StringBuilder()
    while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append("$line\n")
    }
    reader.close()
}
```